What does "living walls of jet" mean in Donne's "The Flea"?
In John Donne's "The Flea", there's an extended conceit where the speaker and whoever he's speaking to are compared to a flea biting the woman, their blood mingling in the flea. The second verse goes like this:

Oh stay, three lives in one flea spare,
Where we almost, nay more than married are.
This flea is you and I, and this
Our marriage bed, and marriage temple is;
Though parents grudge, and you, w'are met,
And cloistered in these living walls of jet.
    Though use make you apt to kill me,
    Let not to that, self-murder added be,
    And sacrilege, three sins in killing three.

I'm having trouble understanding what "living walls of jet" are in this context. "jet", aside from engines, is a word associated with liquid coming out in a tight stream. While that may be applicable to the metaphor, I'm not quite getting what this means in the surface-level reading of the poem. What is a "wall" of jet? The phrase refers to the flea, but in what way?

But jet is also a hard black stone used to make jewelry and other decorative objects. And "living walls of jet" makes much more sense with this definition. This is where the phrase jet black comes from — it has nothing to do with streams of liquid.

That's true, @PeterShor, but since we've been discussing blood - i.e. liquid - my association was with the definition of "jet" that's relevant to liquid.

"Jet" is not in C. T. Onions's A Shakespeare Glossary, W. W. Skeat's A glossary of Tudor and Stuart words, Especially from the Dramatists (Oxford: Clarendon Press, 1914) or A Table Alphabeticall, contayning and teaching the true writing and vnderstanding of hard vsuall English words by Robert Cawdry (third edition, 1617). Fortunately, Wiktionary provides the following definitions (separately from the modern meaning):


(mineralogy) A hard, black form of coal, sometimes used in jewellery.
The colour of jet coal, deep grey.


So Donne imagines the inside of a flea as having the colour of jet. Strictly speaking, fleas aren't black or deep grey but dark brown, but "jet" rhymes with "met".
Update: in response to Kate Bunting's comment "Surely the 'walls of jet' is the flea's 'skin' (exoskeleton)?"
It is unclear what Donne knew about the circulatory system or the digestive system of fleas. (Even knowledge of the human circulatory system was limited. John Donne died in 1631, so I don't know if "The Flea" was written before or after the publication of William Harvey's De Motu Cordis in 1628.) Whether Donne was thinking of the flea's exoskeleton or the "walls" of its digestive system does not seem critical to the understanding of the poem.

Jet can also be dark brown. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_(gemstone)

Inside of a flea, it's too dark to read.

Surely the 'walls of jet' is the flea's 'skin' (exoskeleton)?

Hooke observed a flea under his microscope and described it as "adorn'd with a curiously polish'd set of sable Armour"

@ClaraDíazSanchez Robert Hooke was born in 1635, four years after John Donne's death, so Donne would not have know about Hooke's findings.

@Tsundoku True, I was just saying that "sable armour" does seem similar to sheets of jet.

Two further points to support this reading, compared to OP’s suggestion of the sense of “stream of fluid”: (1) The OED dates that sense back only to 1661, later than the poem, whereas the “hard black coal” sense dates back to 1398 (and related senses like “dark black”, “black marble” also to the 15th century). (2) Grammatically, the poem uses jet as a mass noun, which fits the “coal” sense (and similar senses), while the various other senses, including “stream of fluid”, are ordinarily count nouns.

I wasn't suggesting a reference to the flea's internal anatomy - just that Donne imagines the blood mixing 'inside' the flea, whose 'outside' is black and shiny like jet.
